# remove disk after pvs output

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, lvm

psv command has show below output after I removed physical disk. That disk has xfs filesystem and belog to lvm partition. Before I was removing disk, I did unmount filesystem and I ran below command.

echo 1 > /sys/block/sd#/device/delete

how to I delete a disk to no see the warnning below? and How can I get rid of the warning without rebooting

```
pvs output:
/dev/vg_u02/lv_u02: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
/dev/vg_u02/lv_u02: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 53682831360: Input/output error
/dev/vg_u02/lv_u02: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 53682888704: Input/output error
/dev/vg_u02/lv_u02: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
```

Answer (score 1):

## how to I delete a disk to no see the warnning below?

- In order to delete a disk that is part of LVM you need to first make sure that no space is being used. To find out how much space is actually being occupied issue the following command:

  > root@bbb01:~# pvs -o +pv_used
- You should get an output like this:

  > PV             VG    Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree Used
  >   /dev/sda2      vgbbb lvm2 a--    39.52g      0   39.52g
  >   /dev/sdb1 vgbbb lvm2 a--  1020.00m 508.00m 512.00m
- As you can see sdb1 has **512.00m** (512MB) occupied, so I need to reallocate this space with the following command (assuming you have 512MB free in another PV):

  > root@bbb01:~# pvmove /dev/sdb1
- LVM will move the 512MB to another PV that has enough room to allocate that space. Now you shoud see the **Used** column should look like this:

  > PV         VG    Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree    Used
  >   /dev/sda2  vgbbb lvm2 a--    39.52g       0  39.52g
  >   /dev/sdb1 vgbbb       lvm2 a--  1020.00m 1020.00m     0
- Here you can see it shows **0** and the **PSize** and **PFree** columns are now equal **1020.00m** (1GB/1024MB). Now we need to reduce de VG like this:

  > root@bbb01:~# vgreduce vgbbb /dev/sdb1
- Finally, you can remove the PV like this:

  > root@bbb01:~# pvremove /dev/sdb1
- To confirm just run the **pvs** command which output should be similar to this:

  > PV         VG    Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  >   /dev/sda2  vgbbb lvm2 a--  39.52g    0

## How can I get rid of the warning without rebooting?

- I did exactly what you did and I just delete de LV involved. In your case would be:

  > lvremove /dev/vg_u02/lv_u02
- Now you should see the removed disk as **unknown device** in the output of the **pvs** command:

  > PV             VG    Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
  >   /dev/sda2      vgbbb lvm2 a--    39.52g       0
  >   unknown device vgbbb lvm2 a-m  1020.00m 1020.00m
- Finally tell LVM to remove missing PVs, in your case like this:

  > vgreduce vg_u02 --removemissing
- Now run the **pvs** command and confirm you have no errors.

Hope this helps.